# intellij:project level jdk not taken up by sbt

Tags: java, intellij-idea, sbt

I have configured jdk 17 for my scala project in intellij, but when I run 'sbt clean compile' I still see it targeting Java 8 which is one pointed by my JAVA_HOME:

```
>sbt clean compile
[info] welcome to sbt 1.5.8 (Azul Systems, Inc. Java 1.8.0_282)
```

I expect it to target Java 17.

How can I get it working?

Answer (score 0):

intellij-->file-->project structure-->project setting-->project-->select you java version

Comment: That's what I did.